# Array not indexed after array_filter() is called on it

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering

Here is my code for filtering an array of products by currency.

```
$filtered = array_filter($products->data, function ($item) use ($request) {
   return strpos($item->id, strtoupper($request->currency)) !== false;
});

return $filtered;
```

The problem is that sometimes the filtered array is formatted like this:

```
[
  {
    id: "JPY_SNAP",
    object: "product",
    active: true,
  }
]
```

And with other currencies formatted like this:

```
{
   1: {
     id: "GBP_SNAP",
     object: "product",
     active: true,
   }
}
```

Why is this happening? This makes no sense to me.

Thanks

Comment: This happens on conversion to json, I presume?

Comment: This happens e.g. because the array starts with an index  `!= 0`; rearrange the indices with `$filtered = array_values($filtered);` to see if this is indeed your problem.

Comment: Thanks! `array_values($filtered);` worked.